# TinyMCE doesn't appear when loading through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I got two pages. page1 and page2. In page2 theres a tinymce init:

```
$(document).ready(function(){              
     tinymce.init({
         selector: "textarea",
         theme: "modern"             
     });
});
```

In page1 it request page2 through an ajax request and displays the html.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "page2.php",
     success: function(data) {
         $("#ToolFrame").html(data);
     }
});
```

But when i do this the textarea is just normal. But TinyMCE appears when i manually navigate to page2 without an AJAX request.
It doesn't show any error messages in the console.

How can i fix this to show TinyMCE on the first page with an AJAX request?

Comment: What is the train of thought behind this exactly?

Comment: Well its a very simplified version of what i am making. I got a navigation bar with links and when the user clicks a link the frame gets loaded with a page (in this case a tinymce editor) The only thing is the editor won't load.

Comment: Is this frame in an actual page and why not create a new tinymce for it? Why get the tinymce editor from another page?

Comment: Maybe this helps understanding it: http://gyazo.com/f8c3ab063a4a8ac8afcbca7d7707fe09 and http://gyazo.com/6214b2fdf2ded8b7cd3eadf6022d7eb7 The links load a specific tool which is coded in a page.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your tinyMCE code within the success callback just after the .html(data);

```
$.ajax({
     url: "page2.php",
     success: function(data) {
         $("#ToolFrame").html(data);
         tinymce.init({
             selector: "textarea",
             theme: "modern"             
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: Tried this but no effect to the textarea.

Comment: Is your tinymce source called in page1 ?

Comment: Yes, but it seems i cant even do simple DOM modifications such as $("#test").hide(); to the AJAX loaded page.